# Selecting objects in Doctrine

Tags: object, select, doctrine

```
        $queryBuilder
            ->add('select', 'd.item')
            ->add('from', 'Entities:TypeDetail d')
            ->add('where', $queryBuilder->expr()->andx(
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->gt('d.dateValue', $dates['start']),
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->lt('d.dateValue', $dates['end']))
            );
```

TypeDetail (the table) has the following fields:

`id, dateValue, itemId`

And the model in Symfony is:

`id, dateValue, item (object)`

What I want to do is get a result containing only the `item` objects. I don't want the item id or any of the date values (while I do need them to filter the query, I don't actually care about them coming back in the response).

Is that possible? Obviously `d.item` as the select is not working!

Cheers

Comment: Is 'item' an entity, stored as an id to another table?

Comment: Yep, that's right. So in the database it's stored as "ItemId" but on the actual TypeDetail entity object, "Item" is an object itself.

Comment: I think that selecting one column returns an array, not a hydrated object. I think you should try using `$qb->getArrayResult();` and see if you get an array.

Comment: Yes, it looks like you need to use getArrayResult or look into partial objects on the doctrine documentation.

Comment: I get this error when I try that: `UndefinedMethodException: Attempted to call method "getArrayResult" on class "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder" in C:\...\Controller\DefaultController.php line 90. Did you mean to call: "getFirstResult"?` - any ideas? Do I need to call getQuery() before getArrayResult()?

Comment: Yes get the query first.

Comment: I'm getting `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 9 near 'item FROM Entities:TypeDetail': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.` now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56242/discussion-between-theodore-enderby-and-b85411).